# Python: append a list from a dictionary with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, append

I have a dictionary from which I want to filter out and append the results in another dictionary. The condition is if the difference between two first elements (for example 31 - 30  = 1) in the dictionary is smaller than 5 then add the associated second element of the dictionary and append it in a new dictionary else keep the same first element with the associated second element.

```
a = {"20" : "1.5", "30" : "2.0", "31" : "1.0", "40" : "1", "50" : "1.5"}
listb = []
listc = []
newdict = {}
for key in a:
    b = key
    c = a[key]
    listb.append(b)
    listc.append(c)

for i in range(len(listb)):
    low = listb[i]
    high = listb[i+1]
    diff = int(high) - int(low)
#     print(low)
    if (diff > 5):
        num = listc[i]
#         print(num)
        num_a = listb[i]
#         print(num_a)
        newdict[[num_a][i]] = num
        print((newdict))
    else:
        num = listc[i] + listc[i+1]
        print(num)
        num_a = listb[i+1]
        print(num_a)
        newdict[[num_a][i]] = num
print(newdict)
```

The output of this should look something like

a = {"20" : "1.5", "31" : "3.0", "40" : "1", "50" : "1.5"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only other answer requires the use of Pandas then I feel compelled to offer an alternative (I hate Pandas).

This should give what you describe. I'm not currently able to test though.

```
a = {"20" : "1.5", "30" : "2.0", "31" : "1.0", "40" : "1", "50" : "1.5"}
# your listb and listc are just a.keys() and a.values(). So I'm going to delete all of this listb listc setup stuff.
newdict = {}

skip = False  # This is a pretty brute force way to just check whether we've already accounted for the "next" value. Otherwise you will double count.

for i in range(len(a.keys())):
    if skip:
        skip = False
        continue
    low = a.keys()[i]
    high = a.keys()[i+1]
    diff = abs(int(high) - int(low)) # If "diff" is actually meant to be a diff, then we need to use abs
    if diff > 5:
        newdict[a.keys()[i]] = a.values()[i]
    else:
        newdict[a.keys()[i]] = a.values()[i] + a.values()[i+1]
        skip = True
print(newdict)
```

Please note that if you have several keys in a row that are all < 5 apart, this might not behave as expected. It also isn't clear from the description what you would actually want in a case where the keys were, eg, 40, 44, 48 (group 40 and 44 or group all 3 numbers?). But based on what you describe the above implements it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are comparing each element with the one 'before' or 'after' it, you want to use an ordered data structure. Since dictionaries are only 'insertion ordered', you cannot reliably check the first item with the one right after. So, you might want to use a list of tuples. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but I tried to interpret it with this code. I hope this helps :)

```
# Creating a as a list of tuples so that they are ordered
a = [(20, 1.5), (30, 2.0), (31, 1.0), (40, 1), (50, 1.5)]
new_list = []

# you looped through len(a), but you should loop through len(a) - 1 so that you don't get an index error
for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    # The first element of each tuple
    low_key = a[i][0]
    high_key = a[i+1][0]

    if high_key - low_key < 5:
        sum = a[i+1][1] + a[i][1]
        new_tuple = (high_key, sum)
        new_list.append(new_tuple)
    else:
        new_list.append((low_key, a[i][1]))
        # need to check if last element, bc only looping through len(a) - 1
        if i == len(a) - 1:
            new_list.append((high_key, a[i+1][1]))
print(new_list)
```

Comment: Sam, Thank you so much for looking at this problem. Your solution works perfectly for my case! Thanks again!

Comment: Dictionaries are ordered since I think 3.6

Comment: this solution is better than pandas

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to convert first into `Pandas dataframe` and do your calculations there then convert it back to dictionary?

```
d = {"20" : "1.5", "30" : "2.0", "31" : "1.0", "40" : "1", "50" : "1.5"}
df = pd.Series(d)
df = df.reset_index().astype(float)
df['id']= df['index'].diff().shift(-1).fillna(10).values
df = df[df['id']>5]
df = df.set_index(['index'])
df = df.drop('id', axis=1)
df.to_dict()
{0: {20.0: 1.5, 31.0: 1.0, 40.0: 1.0, 50.0: 1.5}}
```

Comment: Thank you XXavier for taking time to look in to this problem. It is a good approach! Just in the output it should be {20.0: 1.5, 31.0: 3.0, 40.0: 1.0, 50.0: 1.5} but can make those changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear on what you're trying to do, but I think with a couple of comments, you might be able to fix your code to achieve your objective, even if I don't fully understand what that objective is.

A dict is inherently unsorted, but I believe your algorithm inherently requires that the keys be in increasing order.

I'd change the second and third line to:

```
listb = sorted(a.keys())
listc = [a[k] for k in listb]
```

Next you probably want to loop to len(listb) - 1. Otherwise listb[I + 1] will be out of bounds. Maybe you could check out the enumerate function, but then you'd need to check for being on the last iteration, and handle accordingly.

Finally, you could use some better variable names. a, listb, and listc doesn't really convey much meaning. Even a, a_keys, and a_values would have been easier to follow, but a better description of what a represents would be better again.